# Query Only Duplicated Records

Tags: soql, query, leads, duplicate-management

One of my sales reps accidentally uploaded Lead records list twice into the Salesforce prod environment. How can I delete duplicated records?

I've already used a query to find all records. The problem is that there are records like:

```
Company             Edit Date        Field / Event     First Name   Last Name
7 ELEVEN STORE #10104A  04/01/2017 18:30    Created.    7   ELEVEN
7 ELEVEN STORE #10104A  04/01/2017 18:28    Created.    7   ELEVEN
7-ELEVEN STORE #10110A  04/01/2017 18:28    Created.    7-ELEVEN    INC
7-ELEVEN STORE #10110A  04/01/2017 18:30    Created.    7-ELEVEN    INC
7 ELEVEN STORE #10120H  04/01/2017 18:28    Created.    7   ELEVEN
7 ELEVEN STORE #10120H  04/01/2017 18:30    Created.    7   ELEVEN
7-ELEVEN STORE #10146A  04/01/2017 18:30    Created.    7   ELEVEN
7-ELEVEN STORE #10146A  04/01/2017 18:28    Created.    7   ELEVEN
7-ELEVEN STORE #10147A  04/01/2017 18:28    Created.    7-ELEVEN    INC
7-ELEVEN STORE #10147A  04/01/2017 18:30    Created.    7-ELEVEN    INC
```

What criteria can I use in my query to get only the duplicated records?

Answer (score 4):

You must have got a success file stored on your local machine after insertion of records. Take the last files from the two record insertion files and take the id's from them. Delete those id's via the data-loader.

Comment: Very good thought... does the Sales Rep have this result file?

Comment: The person who has inserted the record will have that file on his system. In your case if 'Sales Rep' has inserted the records then he will for sure have the same.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend in an urgent scenario like this (and assuming you have the "power" to be so decisive) using the Developer Console to run some Anonymous Apex to draw out a list and delete the duplicate records

[image: Dev Console]

Looking at your data you can probably use the CreatedDate (and maybe the CreatedById field to narrow to the user) field to determine whether the leads were created at 18:28 or 18:30? Again, use the developer console Query Editor to tweek a query that gets the records and delete them

```
List<Lead> deadLeads = [SELECT CreatedDate, CreatedById FROM Lead WHERE CreatedDate = 2017-01-04T18:28:00.000+0000];
delete deadLeads;
```

I might also consider taking advantage of the Salesforce Matching Rules and Deduplication tools to either resolve this issue (by running them over existing data) and to stop the Sales Rep doing this again.

Comment: This query may delete other records also which may be created by other user at the same time.

Comment: I've tried to execute the following query:

Comment: SELECT Name, Company, Address, Contact_Name__c, Status__c, OwnerId, CreatedById, CreatedDate FROM Lead where CreatedById = '0051400000C6n2f' AND CreatedDate = 2017-01-04T18:28:00.000+0000

Comment: In order to get only the records created during this time 2017-01-04T18:28:00.000+0000 but instead I received: "Sorry, no records returned." Could you please advise what else I need to add or exclude in the query to make it work and give me only the duplicated records?

Comment: Replace the time stamp with the word YESTERDAY - and that should definitely load a tonne of records for that user, and then assert that the actual time stamp is 28 minutes and 0 seconds - which is probably unlikely (I would say a 1 in 60 chance!) you might have to tweek your query to use < and > operators to make a little window of a few seconds if the data load was slow.

Comment: and @AmitChaudhary - I suggested using the CreatedById in my answer for that exact reason... and also, as it is not impossible the user was manually making leads at the same time by other means, I recommend using the dev console to make sure your query returns the right stuff before deleting. It may be possible to include other criteria to ensure only the dataloaded leads are selected :)